# how to Send to Kindle for Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, ebooks, amazon, kindle

Does the "send to Kindle" [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sendtokindle/) not work for Firefox from Ubuntu?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ firefox -version
Mozilla Firefox 59.0.1
thufir@dur:~$
```

From the Firefox site it's not [exactly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/) clear what the latest version is.  Perhaps there's a compatibility issue?

tangential to:

https://superuser.com/q/1306659/55747

Comment: You should be able to email files directly to your kindle. Check your device settings for your kindle account email address

Comment: @chaskes yeh, but downloading then e-mailing html adds extra steps I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken directly from the link you provided:

> Not compatible with Firefox Quantum

Firefox Quantum is any version higher and including Firefox 57.

> Perhaps there's a compatibility issue?

The add-on in question isn’t compatible with Firefox 59 on any operating system.  You would have to use the long term support version to use this particular add-on.